# Python operation on CNTK layers

Tags: c#, python, bit-manipulation

I am not a python person, trying to understand how to convert some Python Code to C# Code:

```
# model parameters
with default_options(bias=False): # all the projections have no bias
    attn_proj_enc   = Stabilizer(enable_self_stabilization=enable_self_stabilization) >> Dense(attention_dim, init=init, input_rank=1) # projects input hidden state, keeping span axes intact
    attn_proj_dec   = Stabilizer(enable_self_stabilization=enable_self_stabilization) >> Dense(attention_dim, init=init, input_rank=1) # projects decoder hidden state, but keeping span and beam-search axes intact
    attn_proj_tanh  = Stabilizer(enable_self_stabilization=enable_self_stabilization) >> Dense(1            , init=init, input_rank=1) # projects tanh output, keeping span and beam-search axes intact
attn_final_stab = Stabilizer(enable_self_stabilization=enable_self_stabilization)
```

This code is a snippet from here: [CNTK/bindings/python/cntk/layers/models/attention.py](https://github.com/microsoft/CNTK/blob/master/bindings/python/cntk/layers/models/attention.py)

My question is, what is the `>>` operator actually doing?

[Stabilizer](https://github.com/microsoft/CNTK/blob/c7bc93fde7d206f71d98a13420b6f2140a97cf20/bindings/python/cntk/layers/blocks.py#L137) is a layer as is [Dense](https://github.com/microsoft/CNTK/blob/c7bc93fde7d206f71d98a13420b6f2140a97cf20/bindings/python/cntk/layers/layers.py#L24), so what is occurring to the layers? Is there a fancy [Bitwise Operation](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators) going on here?

Answer (score 0):

I have never seen this before, but Model Instantiation appears to be the answer:

```
Example:
 >>> model = Dense(500) >> Activation(C.relu) >> Dense(10)
 >>> # is the same as
 >>> model = Dense(500) >> C.relu >> Dense(10)
 >>> # and also the same as
 >>> model = Dense(500, activation=C.relu) >> Dense(10)
```

From: [python/cntk/layers/layers.py#L1361](https://github.com/microsoft/CNTK/blob/c7bc93fde7d206f71d98a13420b6f2140a97cf20/bindings/python/cntk/layers/layers.py#L1361)

of:

```
Another example is a GRU layer with projection, which could be realized as 
``Recurrence(GRU(500) >> Dense(200))``,
where the projection is applied to the hidden state as fed back to the next 
step.
``F>>G`` is a short-hand for ``Sequential([F, G])``.
```

From: [python/cntk/layers/sequence.py#L331](https://github.com/microsoft/CNTK/blob/c7bc93fde7d206f71d98a13420b6f2140a97cf20/bindings/python/cntk/layers/sequence.py#L331)

Specifically a Sequence in a Model.